# Could SE ask for more details on the scores in questions

Tags: feature-request

When one asks a question, Music SE asks to "provide details" but doesn't specify what details. In particular when quoting a score example, I think we should ask for:

- Author and title
- several measures before and after to better understand the context

Many questions we see (e.g. what is this symbol? How to play this?) would be much easier to answer if these details were provided, and answering typically puts the burden of finding the score on the person answering.

Comment: IMO, as a community we could take more advantage of the closing as unclear. If you need clarity before it can be answered, then closing it as unclear makes sense as a general SE principal.

Comment: @Dom but we don't do it. Apparently we are a helpful community and we try to help people. And that's great, except the process could be easier and more efficient if we suggested such things to person creating a question.

Comment: FWIW, I don't hesitate to leave a comment and/or vote to close questions as described, and you'd certainly have my support should you choose to do the same. It still puts the burden on the community, but that would be true even with updated "Ask Question" messaging. I'd be in favor up updating, say, relevant help or Wiki pages, but greater support from the active community would go a long way.